# Cache coherence- MESI protocol

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, second-level-cache, mesi

Can there be a case in a cache employing a MESI protocol (has l1 and l2 inclusivity employed) where l2 can send an invalid instruction to an already invalid line in l1.

Answer (score 1):

An "invalidate request", you mean?

I guess so, if L2 doesn't filter its requests according to what it knows about L1, it might just always send an INVD to L1 every time it evicts a line.  No idea if this is plausible for a real design.  (Eviction from L2 could be caused by a HW or SW prefetch into L2, rather than in response to L1 write-back.)

Or if the CPU core can invalidate a line in L1 at the same time that L2 is sending an invalidate, the INVD could arrive in L1 after it's already invalidated the line.

Comment: Good catch on scenario one, missed it. Just wondering if this is part of maintaining inclusive property.

Comment: @IsuruH: Inclusivity is a one-way property.  The larger cache is inclusive of the inner cache, but also holds lines the inner cache doesn't.  It has to be tag-inclusive so it always knows what the inner cache has, even if the inner cache has M state and thus outer has I.  But the inner cache should be able to drop a line any time it wants.  (Normally, e.g. after running `clflush` or an NT store instruction on x86, I think it would also send invalidates to outer caches, but that takes time and to preserve inclusivity L1D has to drop the line *before* it sends a request asking L2 to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

There could be a scenario where the L2 simply does not know if the L1 has the line, because the L1 is allowed to silently drop it.

In fact, if the L2 is inclusive, there's hardly any reason to waste bandwidth when evicting a non-modified line from the L1 (capacity eviction), because the L2 already has a copy and there's no change. It is therefore likely that many lines in the L2 are still there long after they were evicted from the L1. An eviction from the L2 when it finally arrives (later, since it's bigger) would have to send back a snoop to enforce inclusiveness, because it can't be sure if the line is still in the L1 or not.